# Incorrect position views in RecycleView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a `recyclerview` and I wrote below `xml` code for Rows UI. the row UI shows in the design part like right to left (I mean first show asset and then asset number) but when I run program in an emulator, I see views in incorrect position (I mean first show asset number and then asset). Why? What is my problem?

RecyclerView part:

```
//Code
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        app:elevation="2dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardViewBackground"
        app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:contentPadding="3dp">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/sdp_showalldevices_activity_lstTasks"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@color/gray_dark"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:divider="@color/darkText"
            android:dividerHeight="5dp"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl">
        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
 //code...
```

recyclerView_row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/cardViewBackground"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="right">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="÷رینتر"
        android:textColor="@color/gray_text"
        android:textSize="15dp"></TextView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textColor="@color/gray_text"
        android:textSize="15dp"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="right">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/qcSerialTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="145463254654"
        android:textColor="@color/gray_text"
        android:textSize="15dp"></TextView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/QcSerial"
        android:textColor="@color/gray_text"
        android:textSize="15dp"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="right">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/assetNumberTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="656dfd54"
        android:textColor="@color/gray_text"
        android:textSize="15dp"></TextView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/AssetNumber"
        android:textColor="@color/gray_text"
        android:textSize="15dp"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

the image of the design part of recyclerView_row.xml

[image]

the image of run program:

[image]

Comment: android:supportsRtl="true" in manifest?

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin Yes. I set supportsRtl in manifest. All of views show in correct position ( rtl or ltr) but I start working with RecyclerView and this is not work with my UI

Comment: Try my answer please, I hope to understand what you want correctly

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin I read your answer  but I want to know why design part is not same with run program?

Comment: For me design part is as output, what is رینتر that you have written? Write an English word to see how it is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="name"
            android:textSize="15dp"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="نام:"
            android:textSize="15dp"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
      >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="QcSerial:"
            android:textSize="15dp"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/qcSerialTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="145463254654"
            android:textSize="15dp"></TextView>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="AssetNumber:"
            android:textSize="15dp"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/assetNumberTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="656dfd54"
            android:textSize="15dp"></TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the preview of my answer:
[image]

And this is output of my answer in emulator:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. It's correct but I want to know in my code, why design part of XML code is not same with run program?

Comment: If my answer is correct, you can check the correct answer @Fahim

Comment: No. It doesn't work for me. It shows correctly in the design part but when I run the program on the device, everything shows like a mirror. instead of shows from left 'QcSerial: 45544545', , I see '46554654 QcSerial'  in the right side!  @MohammadMoeinGolchin

Comment: Please use exactly my answer's code. I have attached outputs. @Fahim

Comment: I checked your code on a new project created, It shows correctly but when I wrote your code in my project, everything shows incorrect! I migrated my project to AndroidX a few days ago and I think after that I have these problems. before everything works good. @MohammadMoeinGolchin

Comment: So problem is another thing, my answer is OK @Fahim

Comment: Check your dependencies, if new project works correctly, copy paste its dependencies in your old project. Of course pay attention to extra dependencies that you have used in your old project.@Fahim

Comment: Yes. Your answer is correct. Do you know how do I solve this problem? My project is big and I don't know what is my problem or where is my problem! @MohammadMoeinGolchin

Comment: As I said in last comment, compare dependency of old and new projects, if the code works correctly in new project, it is very good for you.@Fahim

Comment: All of things are the same.. @MohammadMoeinGolchin

Comment: I think if you are sure that dependencies are the same and code works different in two projects, you can ask another question about it.@Fahim

Comment: You have checked android:supportsRtl="true" in both manifests?@Fahim

Comment: Yes android:supportsRtl sets true in both. Ok, I ask another question. Thanks @MohammadMoeinGolchin

Answer (score 1):

if you are building an app in Arabic, Urdu, Hebrew, etc... or any language that is written from right to left you should set `android:supportsRtl` to `true`, that's how you tell the layout to be from right to left, and The default value of this attribute is false.

```
<application android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        tools:replace="android:supportsRtl">
                 .......
    </application>
```

**Edit**

just call `setReverseLayout(true)` for your `LayoutManager` :

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true);
layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
```

Comment: I set RTL in manfiest File and all of the views show correct in my program but this layout in recycler view does not show correctly

Comment: Kashundra I wrote this line before but not worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: `android:layoutDirection="rtl" ` in recylewer view XML

Comment: and also try with `app:reverseLayout="true"` in recylewer view XML